ResizeObserver Loop Error in Monaco Editor on Fullscreen Toggle or Window Resize
Problem Description
I'm using the Monaco Editor in a React component and encountering a persistent error:
ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.
at handleError (``http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:XXXXX:XX``)
at ``http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:XXXXX:XX
This issue arises whenever I toggle the fullscreen mode or resize the browser window. The error points to a ResizeObserver loop problem, which seems to be triggered by Monaco Editor's automaticLayout or the resizing of its parent container.
Here’s the relevant component code:
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { useData } from "../../context/DataContext";

const CodeEditor = ({ language, editorContent, handleChange, theme }) =\> {
const debounceTimeout = useRef(null);
const editorRef = useRef(null);
const latestContent = useRef(editorContent);
const { isGenerating, handleEditorValidation, isFullScreen } = useData();

    const handleEditorChange = (value) => {
        latestContent.current = value;
    
        clearTimeout(debounceTimeout.current);
        debounceTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
            handleChange(latestContent.current);
        }, 3000);
    };
    
    return (
        <div className={`${isFullScreen ? 'h-[60vh] pt-1' : 'h-[55vh]'} w-full rounded-lg`}>
            <Editor
                onValidate={handleEditorValidation}
                language={language}
                value={editorContent}
                theme={theme}
                onMount={(editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
                onChange={handleEditorChange}
                options={{
                    automaticLayout: true,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontFamily: "cursive",
                    fontLigatures: true,
                    lineNumbers: "on",
                    minimap: { enabled: true },
                    scrollbar: {
                        verticalScrollbarSize: 20,
                        horizontalScrollbarSize: 10,
                    },
                    tabSize: 8,
                    insertSpaces: true,
                    formatOnType: true,
                    formatOnPaste: true,
                    wordWrap: "off",
                    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
                    renderLineHighlight: "all",
                    readOnly: isGenerating,
                    cursorBlinking: "smooth",
                    suggestOnTriggerCharacters: true,
                    quickSuggestions: true,
                    parameterHints: { enabled: true },
                    folding: true,
                    occurrencesHighlight: true,
                    autoClosingBrackets: "always",
                    autoClosingQuotes: "always",
                    guides: {
                        indentation: true,
                        highlightActiveBracketPair: true,
                    },
                    bracketPairColorization: { enabled: true },
                }}
            />
        </div>

\`
);
};

export default CodeEditor;

Root Cause
Monaco Editor's automaticLayout Setting: When automaticLayout: true, the Monaco Editor relies on a ResizeObserver to handle resizing. If the container's size changes rapidly, this can trigger a loop of resize events.
Parent Container Resizing: Toggling fullscreen or resizing the browser window affects the parent container's dimensions, causing frequent layout recalculations.
Unnecessary Reflows: If the Editor component or its container modifies DOM properties within the observer's callback, it can create feedback loops.
